# Why does my OR condition cause the WHERE condition to be ignored in the results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT TOP 50
    C.task
    , C.dv_state
    , C.opened_at
    , C.dv_assignment_group
    , C.dv_subcategory
FROM [dbo.].[sn_customer_task] C WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE C.dv_assignment_group IN ('Support', 'Payment') 
AND opened_at >= '2022 3-1- 00:00:00')
OR C.dv_subcategory ='Research;
```

I would like for the results to return only the data for assignment_group under 'Support' and 'Payment'.

I've tried placing the parentheses around what follows the WHERE and OR clauses.

Comment: Read up on logical operator precedence, and then add brackets as required.

Comment: [Bad habits: putting `nolock` everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: You seem to have a floating bracket also.

Comment: @Charlieface - nice I knew there had to be a dup somewhere :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `AND` operator has greater precedence than the `OR` operator, so your current code is actually being evaluated as this:

```sql
WHERE
    (C.dv_assignment_group IN ('Support', 'Payment') AND
     opened_at >= '2022-03-01 00:00:00')
    OR C.dv_subcategory = 'Research'
```

You should write it as:

```sql
WHERE C.dv_assignment_group IN ('Support', 'Payment') AND
      (opened_at >= '2022-03-01 00:00:00' OR C.dv_subcategory ='Research')
```